# firefox SDK, addon development

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, sdk

Until now i have the following code.

**index.js**

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var button = ToggleButton({
  id: "my-button",
  label: "seedXXX.in",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon.png",
    "32": "./icon_48.png",
    "64": "./icon_128.png"
  },
  onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: self.data.url("popup.html"),
  onHide: handleHide
});

function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });
  }
}

function handleHide() {
  button.state('window', {checked: false});
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "title": "seedXXX.in (DE)",
  "name": "seed-XXXde",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "XXX",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "XXX",
  "permissions": {
  "cross-domain-content": ["https://seedXXX.in"]
},
  "engines": {
    "firefox": ">=38.0a1",
    "fennec": ">=38.0a1"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

**popup.html**

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>seedXXX.in</title>
        <link href="css/plugin.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="libs/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>

        <center><a href="https://seedXXX.in/" target="_blank"><img src="https://seedXXX.in/img/logo.png"></a>
        <hr>

        <input class="formField" type="text" placeholder="Strain Suchen..." maxlength="50" name="keyword" id="keyword" required><br><div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
        <hr>
        <button class="btn" onclick="doSearch()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Suchen</button>
        </center>

        <script>

          function doSearch() {
          // check if keyword is not empty
          if(document.getElementById('keyword').value != '') {

          // set variables and do the search
          var strainName = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
          var urlEncode = encodeURIComponent(strainName);
          var replaced = urlEncode.replace(/%20/g, "+");
          var searchURL = "https://seedXXX.in/searchstrain.php?keyword="+replaced+"&lang=de";

          // do the search
          window.open(searchURL, '_blank');

          }else{

          // focus if 'keyword' is empty
          document.getElementById("keyword").className = "formField fieldEmpty";
          document.getElementById("keyword").focus();
          setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("keyword").className = "formField"; }, 1500);

          }
    }
    </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Until now all went good, on my ... part i want to add the following (this works on website and in chrome without any problems):

```
// liveSearch
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#keyword").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://seedXXX.in/ajax_apps.php",
        data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            //$("#keyword").css("background","#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#suggesstion-box").show();
            $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
            $("#keyword").css("background","#FFF");
        }
        });
    });
});
```

It don't works if i put this part into the popup.htmt nothing get shows on keyup. Can anybody help me (noob :)) with this problem to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the console to see if there are any errors? Also you should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi, yes the console dont say anything, but i think the call of ajax is not on the correct place here? Maybe it must be in index.js but dont know how to to make it at all.